# How to display specific data from array?

Tags: laravel

How can I correct display data from array. I guess it's a foreach loop, but I do not know how to bite it. I just need only header. It's in table calendars.

Thanks so much!

```
@foreach($list as $item)
    {{ $item->header }}
@endforeach
```

I tried the above code but throws out an error, unknown value "header"

```
@foreach($results as $type => $list)
    <div class="single-contact-information mb-30">
        <h3>{{ $type }} </h3>
        {{ $list }}  
    </div>
@endforeach

[{"id":1,"header":"test","description":"<p>test<\/p>","date":"2020-12-12"}]
```

---

Edit:
SearchController:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $results = [];
    $results['calendars'] = DB::table('calendars')->where('header', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

    return view('pages.search', ['results' => $results]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
[{"id":1,"header":"test","description":"<p>test<\/p>","date":"2020-12-12"}]
```

Above value is json then use below code

```
    $list = [{"id":1,"header":"test","description":"<p>test<\/p>","date":"2020-12-12"}];



@foreach($list as $item)
    {{ $item['header'] }}
@endforeach

    $list = json_decode($list);

    @foreach($list as $item)
        {{ $item['header'] }}
    @endforeach
```

**Updated Answer**

```
@foreach(json_decode($list) as $item)
        {{ $item->header }}
    @endforeach
```

Comment: but should I decode json in SearchController? Look my edit

Comment: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: Thats it :* Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

used `json_decode` function here

```
@foreach(json_decode($list) as $item)
    {{ $item['header'] }}
@endforeach
```